# What is Jake Sullivan's policy on arming and supplying Taiwan?

Tags: united-states, china, military, foreign-policy, taiwan

I'd like to know what the current [US National Security Advisor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/National_Security_Advisor_(United_States)) ([Jake Sullivan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jake_Sullivan))'s position on arming and supplying Taiwan is.

> The Assistant to the President for National Security Affairs (APNSA), commonly referred to as the National Security Advisor (NSA), is a senior aide in the Executive Office of the President, based at the West Wing of the White House. The National Security Advisor serves as the principal advisor to the President of the United States on all national security issues.

Is there any information on how Sullivan may have articulated his own opinion or advised the President?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: I don't see where the issue is. I've set forth a question: What are Jake Sullivan's views on arming Taiwan, defending/deploying troops to Taiwan, and actions against China for anti-Taiwanese aggression? I don't see how that's non-specific, I've asked about what one person's policy is regarding Taiwan with three areas I'd specifically like to know about.

Comment: Your edit looks great! I added a few links and an extra sentence to try to head off comments about the role of a presidential advisor in making policy. Your question is specifically about Sullivan and not US policy in general.

Comment: I don't see the difference between the edited version of this question and [your other question](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/72235/what-is-jake-sullivans-position-on-defending-taiwan?noredirect=1&lq=1). For my answer to this one, see that one. xD

Comment: This question pertains to providing Taiwan with arms and other indirect support. The other question is regarding direct actions like deploying troops and aircraft to Taiwan.